# Use an SVG Image in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to embed an existing SVG inside a chart that I am generating using HighCharts. Can someone point to an example on how to do that? I have skimmed through Highcharts documentation, but did not find any references to using existing SVGs.

```
https://elinux.org/images/c/cb/Raspberry_Pi_Logo.svg
```

I have seen PNGs embedded in highcharts, like this example

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-image-on-chart/)

Comment: Simply using the `svg` file url in place of the `png` in your example works (at least in Chrome 65).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6x6bsz6b/